# MVC web framework for python

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I am new to python programming and need to build the project in python. I have done several project in PHP and have knowledge of PHP MVC framework. So I want to use python MVC framework. The problem is that I have access to file server only via FTP connection therefore there is no database server and can't install anything. Is there any MVC framework for python which doesn't needs installation like CI, YII of PHP which are simply transfer via FTP connection. And also in this case how can I use datbase SQLite which doesn't need installation.

Comment: It is off topic to ask for tools or libraries on SO because it attracts opinion only answers. All I can say is that Python has native support for SQLite, and that [django](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info) is a popular tag for a Python MVC framework if you later need help about it. So, read SO info page, search for resources on Internet and make your own opinion.

Comment: Have a look at webpy: http://webpy.org/